# WP Rest API v2 custom endpoints

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wp rest api to feed woocommerce products in my ionic2 app. So, I would like to feed only products with the `in_stock` parameter on true. My Plugin, which communicate between rest api and mobile app is using version 1 of `wp-json/wc/v1/products` but the version 1 is not delivering the `in_stock` parameter, that's why I would like to use `wp-json/wc/v2/products`. This works also without any issue. However, I miss some data in my json response. The following function in my plugin add the geodata and address to the response

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product', array( $this, 'get_vendor_product' ),10,3);

public function get_vendor_product($response, $post, $request){
    if(isset($request['is_vendor']) && $request['is_vendor']==true){
        $vendor_id=$request['vendor_id'];
        $shop_name=WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_shop_name($vendor_id);
        $shop_desc=get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'pv_shop_description',true);

        $response->data['shop_name']= $shop_name;
        $response->data['shop_desc']= $shop_desc;
        $response->data['vendor_id']= $request['vendor_id'];
        $response->data['vendor_address']= get_user_meta($vendor_id,'sow_vendor_address',true);
        $response->data['vendor_geocoding']=  get_user_meta($vendor_id,'sow_vendor_geocoding',true);
    }else if(isset($request['id']) && WCV_Vendors::is_vendor($post->post_author)){
        $response->data['vendor_id']= $post->post_author;
        $shop_name=WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_shop_name($post->post_author);
        $shop_desc=get_user_meta( $post->post_author, 'pv_shop_description',true);

        $response->data['shop_name']= $shop_name;
        $response->data['shop_desc']= $shop_desc;
        $response->data['vendor_address']= get_user_meta($post->post_author,'sow_vendor_address',true);
        $response->data['vendor_geocoding']=  get_user_meta($post->post_author,'sow_vendor_geocoding',true);
    }else{
        if(WCV_Vendors::is_vendor($post->post_author)){
            $response->data['vendor_address']= get_user_meta($post->post_author,'sow_vendor_address',true);
            $response->data['vendor_geocoding']=  get_user_meta($post->post_author,'sow_vendor_geocoding',true);
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

I could not identify, why when I use version 2 (wp-json/wc/v2/products) the geo data is not in the response. Does the version 2 use other endpoints?

Comment: where your geo data saved in database?

Comment: in the postmeta table

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I did not understand your question before writing this comment.

I think you want to return only those products which are in_stock. Correct?

Please refer my answer below.

Comment: Can you answer how one can modify the wp-json response for a specific post only See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330395/how-to-modify-title-in-wp-json-response-but-only-for-a-specific-post

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one by the condition "in_stock" as true but the issue is that if you will not return anything when "in_stock" is false then woocommerce automatically return product response as null.

You can be modified with the blank array instead of null by else condition.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product', array( $this, 'get_vendor_product' ),10,3);

public function get_vendor_product($response, $post, $request){

if( $response->data['in_stock'] === true ) {

    if(isset($request['is_vendor']) && $request['is_vendor']==true){
        $vendor_id=$request['vendor_id'];
        $shop_name=WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_shop_name($vendor_id);
        $shop_desc=get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'pv_shop_description',true);

        $response->data['shop_name']= $shop_name;
        $response->data['shop_desc']= $shop_desc;
$response->data['vendor_id']= $request['vendor_id'];
        $response->data['vendor_address']= get_user_meta($vendor_id,'sow_vendor_address',true);
$response->data['vendor_geocoding']=  get_user_meta($vendor_id,'sow_vendor_geocoding',true);
    }else if(isset($request['id']) && WCV_Vendors::is_vendor($post->post_author)){
        $response->data['vendor_id']= $post->post_author;
        $shop_name=WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_shop_name($post->post_author);
        $shop_desc=get_user_meta( $post->post_author, 'pv_shop_description',true);

        $response->data['shop_name']= $shop_name;
        $response->data['shop_desc']= $shop_desc;
        $response->data['vendor_address']= get_user_meta($post->post_author,'sow_vendor_address',true);
$response->data['vendor_geocoding']=  get_user_meta($post->post_author,'sow_vendor_geocoding',true);
    }else{
        if(WCV_Vendors::is_vendor($post->post_author)){
        $response->data['vendor_address']= get_user_meta($post->post_author,'sow_vendor_address',true);
        $response->data['vendor_geocoding']=  get_user_meta($post->post_author,'sow_vendor_geocoding',true);
        }

    }
    return $response;
  }
}
```

Comment: This if state does not work. In this way, I don't get any information of this function. But different products have in_stock true. However, I'm wondering why this function works with V1 and not with V2. There seems to be a change.